# phantomJs permission denied

Tags: php, phantomjs

Have a question and I have the feeling it should not be to hard to solve but I'm not really familiar with Phantom Js.

```
$this->phantomProcess($path)->setTimeout(10)->mustRun();
```

This line results in the following error:

```
protected function captureImage($view)
{
    $path = $this->writeFile($view);

    $this->phantomProcess($path)->setTimeout(10)->mustRun();

    return $path;
}

protected function writeFile($view)
{
    file_put_contents($path = 'storage/' . md5(uniqid()) . '.pdf' , $view);

    return $path;
}

protected function phantomProcess($path)
{
    return new Process('bin/phantomjs capture.js ' . $path);
}
```

I'm running the following line:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException' with message 'The command "bin/phantomjs capture.js storage/7c5b791a0c1f131aac5c5ca272a1c891.pdf" failed. Exit Code: 126(Invoked command cannot execute) Working directory: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file ' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf/app/Codecourse/Capture/Capture.php(45): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->mustRun() #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf/app/Codecourse/Capture/Capture.php(24): Codecourse\Capture\Capture->captureImage('<!DOCTYPE html>...') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf/index.php(17): Codecourse\Capture\Capture->load('invoice.php', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pdf/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php on line 239
```

Anybody who can help me out?
Really appreciated,

Comment: Can you check $path properly and its permissions

Comment: @SudharshanNair thanks for your reply. I've updated the code. You can see the path goes to a .pdf in the storage directory. The storage directory has been chmodded to 777

Comment: Where is your error message?

Comment: Sorry, edited again.

Comment: Additional I found this rule within my error_log file: sh: `bin/phantomjs: Permission denied` Should permissions also be changed on the PhantomJs file?

Comment: Sorry guys, Found the error. The error was caused by the wrong version of Phantom. Thank all.